# Authentication and Authorisation like Github using keycloak

Tags: github, keycloak, openid-connect, kong, kong-plugin

We are using Kong API gateway with Keycloak IAM.

We are looking forward to configuring access via Github.

As in Github URL :

```
https://github.com/org-name/username/reponame
```

As in GitHub we have organization repo and each user has different access in an organization repo (read/write) or i can add a specific user to the organization with only one repository access.

and restricting users at API gateway level if no access there.

can someone please help me with how to achieve it using the same with Keycloak and Kong API gateway.